# EWS -C# - send email from one user by another user - the email written in the sent items as a draft

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I have code that send email from one user by another user
and save the email in the send item of the first user.
Everything worked fine until I changed some things in the installations, I tried to change back to what was before, but the email was written in outgoing mail as a draft.

I try to change the version of EWS, but it didn't change anything.
I debugged the code and saw that I had an error about the type object 'EmailMessage'
That's the error: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/cI827.png)

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you provide the exception message? But it looks like the email prop is null.

Comment: In the link above I put a screenshot of the error.
No specific exception was thrown, the email was simply not written as a draft in outgoing mail.
When I debugged I saw that there is an exceptions in this object.
And I don't know why it happens.
thank you